# pandas read_excel doesn't return data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know why the code below works fine when executed from Python interpreter but it returns no value when I "pack" it into the file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
getFile = (input('\nEnter Excel file name: ')).lower()
getTab = (input('\nEnter tab name: ')).lower()
fileName = os.path.join(os.getcwd() + '\\' + getFile)
pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=getTab, header=None)
```

Is there any reason I can't run this code from someFile.py? What I do wrong? Many thanks for your kind help. Please, be forgiving, I'm not a professional or skilful coder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a name to the dataframe into which the data should be read.
Try the code below

```
df= pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=getTab, header=None)
```

If you are working in Jupyter notebook, the below line will print the dataframe

```
df
```

Comment: many thanks for your kind advice, however, it worked with some modification (i don't use Jupyter).
`df = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=getTab, header=None)
print(df)`

Anyway, thanks for giving me a useful hint, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I found a few links with the explanation:

[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe/)

@mohanys, again many thanks for solving my issue.